# SQL Cant change primary key column name after changing other column

Tags: mysql, primary-key, alter-table

Can someone please tell me why this happens.  The original problem is as always much more complex, but I've created a simple test case to reproduce the issue.  First you need a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `test_a` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_a`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then you need to try to alter the table with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`
    CHANGE COLUMN `test_b` `new_test_b` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `test_a`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `test_a` `new_test_a` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

and you get this result:

```
Unknown column 'test_a' in 'test'
```

I don't get it.  It works fine when you do each alteration separately but if you do them together it blows up.

---

Addendum...

After studying this a bit, i figured out a few things.  I took a guess that perhaps the compiler (or preprocessor or something) was evaluating the comma separated alter statements in reverse order, there-by changing the test_a column name before it got the the test_b (which would make the 'AFTER `test_a`' part not make sense..   This turned out to be wrong in testing because if you reverse the order of the statements like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `test
    CHANGE COLUMN `test_a` `new_test_a` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
    CHANGE COLUMN `test_b` `new_test_b` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `test_a`;
```

You end up with the same result.

Next I took the assumption that certain types of operations have precedence in a statement like this.  I assumed that all CHANGE COLUMN operations must be taking place before any column ordering operations such as 'AFTER `test_a`'  If this was the case, then it would make sense to reference the new column name in the ordering operation,  like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`
    CHANGE COLUMN `test_b` `new_test_b` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `new_test_a`,
    CHANGE COLUMN `test_a` `new_test_a` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

This worked.  So that must be the answer.  My question i guess has evolved now to what is the order of precedence of the various types of operations.

Note, sorry I am not going to mark any of the current answers correct as they do not actually answer the question, they simply offer alternative ways to do the same thing (or state the obvious).

Comment: It might be because it is renaming testa first because there is dependency on test a in the first alter statement and then trying to modify testb after testa . But since testa is now renamed, hence the error.But you will need to check the documentation of alter to be 100% sure.

Comment: this is the closest to the answer i think, hence the upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`
    CHANGE COLUMN `test_b` `new_test_b` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `test_a`;
ALTER TABLE `test`
    CHANGE COLUMN `test_a` `new_test_a` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```